# How to get the details in a Json object?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I was wondering how to get further details from a Json Object.

This is the Json file:

```
{
    "Shapes": "Models",
    "Square": {
        "Length": 10
    },
    "Rectangle": {
        "Length": 10,
        "Width": 20
    },
    "Circle": {
        "Radius": 5
    },
    "Equilateral": {
        "Side": 10
    },
    "Scalene": {
        "Side1": 10,
        "Side2": 5,
        "Side3": 3
    },
    "Isosceles": {
        "Side1": 10,
        "Side2": 5,
        "Side3": 5
    }
}
```

My code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("filepath"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        Object Square =  jsonObject.get("Square");
        System.out.println("Square: " + Square);
        Object Rect =  jsonObject.get("Rectangle");
        System.out.println("Rectangle: " + Rect);
    }
```

The o/p is like

```
Square: {"Length":10}
Rectangle: {"Length":10,"Width":20}
```

I would like to get further details like "length/Width/Radius"

Comment: Your quoted JSON has the key `Square` listed twice. While I think that's valid JSON, it means that you can't access the first one, only the second one.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. I wanted only 1 square and I added the second one just to test my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square, Rectangle, etc. properties in the example JSON each are JSONObjects with their own properties. To access properties on those JSON objects cast the *Object* to a *JSONObject* instance to access its methods.

```
    (JSONObject) Square = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Square");
    System.out.println("Square: " + Square);
    System.out.println("Square: Length=" + Square.get("Length"));

    JSONObject rect =  (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Rectangle");
    System.out.println("Rectangle: " + rect);
    System.out.printf("Rectangle: Length=%s Width=%s%n",
      rect.get("Length"), rect.get("Width"));
```

BTW, if want to have duplicate keys (e.g. multiple Squares) then you need to represent data as an array (or list) vs a map and make the shape type a property of the shape details (length, width, etc.).

```
  [
   { "shape": "Square", 
     "Length": 6
   },
   { "shape": "Square", 
     "Length": 10
   }
  ]
```

Comment: The second Square is actually not needed. I used it for my testing. I did edit my Json code accordingly. Thanks again.